# MSSQLSERVER Service fails to start after reboot

Tags: sql-server, windows-services

We have recently changed our MSSQLSERVER service from running as a local user to a domain user but we keep having the following problem...

MSSQLSERVER service happily runs as my domain user until we reboot, once we have rebooted the machine, we notice that MSSQLSERVER is not running.

If we open services.msc and try and start MSSQLSERVER, we get the following error:
[image: services-error]

If we go into the properties and set the password, it then shows us the following message:

- The account sqluser@mydomain.com has been granted the Log On As A Service right

And we can then successfully start MSSQLSERVER.

But then if we reboot again, we have to do the above process again once the machine is back up (once again SQL does not start)

Looking in the event log > Security, I can see a Security Audit Failure for sqluser@mydomain.com, with the following Failure Reason:

- Failure Reason:      The user has not been granted the requested logon type at this machine.

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this to ensure it can always start after boot without the user needing to do this 'fix'

Comment: Have you checked that the service account has permission to log on as a service at domain level? if not, most likely the group policy/user permissions are downloaded at restart and, as a result, the log on as service permission is revoked.

Comment: Almost certainly group policy of some kind. Discuss the issue with your network admins.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have a network admin, trying to knock this together ourselves. Im just adding a new GPO to give the domain user log on as a service right, will let you know how it turns out but if you have any suggestions I welcome them

Answer (score 1):

We faced this issue before, we solve it by configure domain ID (service ID) assigned to run MSSQLSERVER service in local Group Policy.

1. Launch gpedit.msc >Computer Configuration >Windows Settings >Security Setting >Local policies >User Rights Assignment >Add the ID under the "Access this computer from the network" and "Log on as a service" policies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the list of users allowed to log on as a service was being over-written by a GPO.

Fix: Update GPO to include this new user to be allowed to log on as a service.